# What does typedef do in C++

Tags: c++, typedef

```
typedef set<int, less<int> > SetInt;
```

Please explain what this code does.

Comment: when i want to type it
what "less" mean in it and is it must to write???
thankx

Comment: Can you give us the code definition of less<int>?

Comment: Seeing as there is no std:: before `set`, `less` then probably refers to `std::less`. Though it could a custom set and less, I doubt it.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This means that whenever you create a `SetInt`, you are actually creating an object of `set<int, less<int> >`.

For example, it makes the following two pieces of code equivalent:

```
SetInt somevar;
```

and

```
set<int, less<int> > somevar;
```

Comment: One should also note that this is an exact synonym, not a new type being introduced. It means that any specialization of templates for SetInt will also apply to set<int, less<int> >. Therefore, it's just a short hand, which is useful for readability or DRY for example.

Answer (score 6):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typedef):

> `typedef` is a keyword in the C and C++ programming languages. It is used to give a data type a new name. The intent is to make it easier for programmers to comprehend source code.

In this particular case, it makes `SetInt` a type name, so that you can declare a variable as:

```
SetInt myInts;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can just use `SetInt` after the `typedef` as if you are using `set<int, less<int>>`. Of course, `typedef` is scope aware.

Comment: You still need a space in '> >', though the C++0x standard may make that unnecessary in the future.

Answer (score 0):

It makes an alias to the type called `SetInt`, which is equivalent to `set<int, less<int> >`.

About your question about less, that refers to [`std::less`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/functional/less/), the comparer that [`set`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/set/) will use to sort your objects.

Answer (score 0):

A typedef in C/C++ is used to give a certain data type another name for you to use.

In your code snippet, `set<int, less<int> >` is the data type you want to give another name (an alias if you wish) to and that name is `SetInt`

The main purpose of using a typedef is to simplify the comprehension of the code from a programmer's perspective. Instead of always having to use a complicated and long datatype (in your case I assume it is a template object), you can choose a rather simple name instead.

Answer (score 0):

The code means that you give an alias or name (SetInt) to the

```
set<int, less<int>>
```

object...i.e. instead of always calling the object as

```
set<int, less<int>>
```

you can just give SetInt as the name and call the object.... just like

```
int i;
```

eg:

```
SetInt setinteger;
```

Comment: You still need a space in '> >', though the C++0x standard may make that unnecessary in the future.